# Using ESP8266-01 with Arduino uno R3

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, wifi

I am trying to learn how to use ESP-01(AI-Cloud, Black Version) with arduino

Initially, I created an adapter for it that has 4 inputs: RX, TX, Vcc(3.3v), GND I checked it and the wiring seems fine then I attached TX of arduino to TX of ESP and same with RX but with a voltage divider (1k ohm,2kohm),I uploaded arduino with a blank sketch and tried to run commands like AT and AT+CWMODE? but I got no response on the serial monitor.I tried to look for a proper tutorial to do this but, all tutorials show how to upload a sketch to ESP rather than arduino. Then I searched and found this piece of code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define DEBUG true

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
                            // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
                            // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 esp8266.begin(115200); // your esp's baud rate might be different



 sendData("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
 sendData("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure as access point
 sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // get ip address
 sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
 sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80
}

void loop()
{
 if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message
 {
   /*
   while(esp8266.available())
   {
     // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
     char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
     Serial.write(c);
   } */

   if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
   {
    delay(1000);

    int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns
                                          // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48

    String webpage = "<h1>Hello</h1>&lth2>World!</h2><button>LED1</button>";

    String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
    cipSend += connectionId;
    cipSend += ",";
    cipSend +=webpage.length();
    cipSend +="\r\n";

    sendData(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
    sendData(webpage,1000,DEBUG);

    webpage="<button>LED2</button>";

    cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
    cipSend += connectionId;
    cipSend += ",";
    cipSend +=webpage.length();
    cipSend +="\r\n";

    sendData(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
    sendData(webpage,1000,DEBUG);

    String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE=";
    closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id
    closeCommand+="\r\n";

    sendData(closeCommand,3000,DEBUG);
   }
 }
}


String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
   String response = "";

   esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

   long int time = millis();

   while( (time+timeout) > millis())
   {
     while(esp8266.available())
     {

       // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
       char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
       response+=c;
     }  
   }

   if(debug)
   {
     Serial.print(response);
   }

   return response;
}
```

I hooked pins according to the code and it worked serial monitor output some lines but with allot of garbage values, This also created a wifi hotspot 'AI-Thinker' which I connected to and opened Ip as shown on debugging. This made ESP try to send string 'webpage' but mostly was garbage.

so my question is, how to properly use esp with arduino to maybe just switch an led on or send data from sensors, super basics?

Is it better to use esp Library and upload sketches to esp and control arduino with it?

Can some one suggest the proper tutorial for this? because even after all this I am still confused that is RX of arduino connected to RX(which makes no sense but given in many of google images) or TX of ESP-01?

Comment: Start troubleshooting the serial connection, Arduino <-> ESP01. In the https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample you find a example that copy data from Serial (PC) to SoftSerial (ESP01). And Rx is supposed to go to Tx and vice versa. Arduino digital pin 0 (Rx) connects to ESP01 pin 2 (Tx) and Arduino digital pin 1 (Tx) connects to ESP01 pin 7 (Rx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ESP8266 + Arduino Uno: Can't send AT Commands](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9571/esp8266-arduino-uno-cant-send-at-commands)

Comment: "_Is it better to use esp Library and upload sketches to esp and control arduino with it?_"? YES!

Comment: @MatsK I was really confused and found that Tx-Rx used when there is need to send commands from arduino code & Tx-Tx used when there is need to send commands from arduino serial monitor this is when arduino isattached to pc via usb, Is this right ?

Comment: @dandavis thanks, so I should use my arduino and its IDE to upload sketches to ESP8266 , and then through ESP's Tx Rx pins control arduino and its sensor because I don't have any ftdi chip ,or 3.3v voltage regulator and hoping arduino is enough for this ?

Comment: Please remove the part "is it better...", that makes your question opinion based and worth closing. Also you should make only one question: this is not a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm that the serial communication is working, connect the ESP to the Arduino D10 and D11 that is used as SoftSerial pins.

```
+----+
| PC |
+--/-+
   |       +---------+
   \-------| Arduino |
     USB   +--.------+
              | SoftSerial
              |
           +--\----+
           | ESP01 |
           +-------+
```

And then upload this code to the Arduino. The code is from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample

```
/*
 Receives from the hardware serial, sends to software serial.
 Receives from software serial, sends to hardware serial.

 The circuit:
 * RX is digital pin 10 (connect to TX of ESP01)
 * TX is digital pin 11 (connect to RX of ESP01)

 Created back in the mists of time
 modified 25 May 2012
 by Tom Igoe
 based on Mikal Hart's example

 This example code is in the public domain.
 */

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // Set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}

void loop() {

  if (mySerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <WiFiEsp.h>
#include <WiFiEspClient.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

...

SoftwareSerial wifiSerial(WIFI_RX, WIFI_TX);
WiFiEspClient WIFI_CLIENT;

...


void setup() {
  wifiSerial.begin(9600); // or 115200
  WiFi.init(&wifiSerial);
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    printLog("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }
  printLog("Connecting to AP ...");
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
  printLog("Connected to AP");  
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TX` pin of the Arduino goes into the `RX` pin of the ESP and vice versa: that's the way serial communication works, apart for voltage level considerations.

Another factor you have to take into consideration is the two devices MUST operate at the same speed, once known as *Baud Rate*: I believe 115200 might be the ESP default speed, but that's programmable.
There are also other two additional parameters which play a role in [serial communication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port), *Parity* and *Data bits*, but the default values are more than likely fine and you shouldn't worry about those.

So, in essence, verify your wiring and set the right speed considering some ESP modules run a firmware using non standard speed for serial comm.